# How to change color of any IP address in iterm?

Tags: linux, ip, colors, iterm2

How can I change the color of any IP address displayed on the iterm2 (CentOS)?

Comment: Other than with a trigger?

Comment: "iterm2 (CentOS)" does not compute. iTerm 2 is a macOS-exclusive app.

Comment: Are you connecting to an iterm session from CentOS or vice versa? Or???